# JavaScript innerHTML for few seconds

Tags: javascript

I followed a tutorial on how to build basic games by using JS/HTML and now I am expanding it. [Game here](https://pages.github.ccs.neu.edu/pamousset/spaceGame./?fbclid=IwAR1P59hWw8SNADg2z5ySAO056LOulpCDgHH0nt4ogana3zqYLzX_zFzoqVU)

- press space to fire
- press the right arrow to turn right and the left one to turn left

I was able to get the location of the collision between an enemy and a missile and add a new `#explosion` to the html by using `innerHTML`. I am confused how I can be able to remove the explosion after 1 second.

```
const explosion = (topEn, leftEn) => {
    document.getElementById('explosions').innerHTML +=
    `
    <div id="explosion" style='
    left:${leftEn}px;
    top: ${topEn}px;
    '></div>
    `;
}


#explosion{
    background-image: url("assets/explosion.png");
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: in might be easier to move from innerHTML into creating a div using `document.createElement`. You could then use setTimeout after 1000 ms and simply call the `el.remove()` I don't have all of your code, so it's hard to give you something more exact, but I'll try to rough out this bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the rest of your code it's hard to give you an exact show, but this is largely what my comment was referring to.

```js
const explosion = (topEn, leftEn, delay = 1000) => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'explosion';
  div.style.top = topEn + 'px';
  div.style.left = leftEn + 'px';

  document.getElementById('explosions').append(div);
  setTimeout(() => {
    div.remove()
  }, delay);
}

explosion(200, 200, 1000);

setTimeout(()=> explosion(300, 400, 800), 500)
```

```css
#explosion {
  background-image: url("assets/explosion.png");
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  /* I added this to be able to see the divs*/
  background-color: red;
}

body, html, #explosions {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="explosions"></div>
```

### Notes:

If you are going to perhaps have multiple elements of the same type (i.e.) explosions in the DOM at the same time you should move to using a class instead of an ID. IDs are *unique* identifiers, so while you *can* have multiple elements with the same ID, it will lead you to unexpected results. If your game will be able to have more than 1 explosion going at any given time, move `#explosion` to `.explosion`